# SEO optimization for AJAX site and dynamic HTML canvas

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api, seo

I have a site that uses AJAX to query the Last.fm database and then dynamically draws a graph of the results on an HTML canvas. In the search function, I have a command that sets window.location.hash to the search parameters. I also have a function that checks if a hash was provided in the url and if so, generates the page.

For example, http://www.thenlistento.com/#!/led+zeppelin will automatically navigate to a search page for Led Zeppelin.

My question is, how do optimize this set up for SEO? Can it be done at all? I've taken a look at Google Webmaster Docs and read over the hashbang protocol, but I'm not totally sure how to apply it to my situation..or even if I can at all.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Link to the site: http://www.thenlistento.com

Answer (score 0):

Start by viewing your site without any style sheets.

Your code looks great and clean!

All your links show as # rather than going to somepage.php/.html etc - it's been a while since I was in to SEO, but if I remember correctly # links were ranked lower than links going to a new page.

Also all your error text is visible on the page without styling, some spiders will rank you lower if they think you're "hiding" text.

You have meta tags/description in etc (although it's still up for debate if they effect your PR).

You mention google webmaster, so I presume you've submitted your site for indexing.

You have a robot.txt file.

So far you've done everything right. I'd say it's time to start on your link building; links from higher ranked related sites to your own.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean that the error text is visible without styling, though?

The site has been submitted for indexing. I'm focused on producing HTML snapshots of searches, so that Google can pick them up. I want to use the hashbangs kind of the way Twitter does with user pages.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with using phantomjs to provide a crawler version at the server side, the phantomjs will render the page, and wait till the page are rendered, then you can get the final html, which will be good for crawlers.

See my solution here: https://github.com/liuwenchao/ajax-seo, it's possible you still need some extra works, because I'm not sure if Canvas will be fully generated with my solution, you are welcome to fork my repository.